# Using a variable from ManyToMany as fields in UpdateView Django 1.10

Tags: python, django

The models which I have defined consist of `RestaurantFeature` which has a many-to-many relationship defined with `RestaurantServing`. The code of my models.py:

```
class RestaurantServing(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(default="")

class RestaurantFeature(models.Model):
    location = models.OneToOneField(
        Location,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        primary_key = True,
    )
    serving = models.ManyToManyField(RestaurantServing)
```

I am now trying to implement and `restaurantfeatures_edit` page where the `serving` can be removed/added/selected ect. The views.py class based method I have written:

```
class RestaurantFeatureEdit(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'Restaurants/restaurantfeature_edit.html'
    model = RestaurantFeature
    fields = ['name', ]
    success_url = '/restaurant'
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
```

This code returns the error that `Unknown field(s) (name) specified for RestaurantFeature`... I already have tried `fields = ['serving.name',]` and adding the multiple models as `model = RestaurantFeature, RestaurantServing`. Could someone help me to get the `name` in my UpdateView?

Comment: `Unknown field(s) (serving__name) specified for RestaurantFeature`, nope!

Comment: Which name would you expect? Each `RestaurantFeature` instance can have multiple `RestaurantServings`. `serving.all()` is a `QuerySet`, `serving` a related manager, not an instance, and should really be called `servings`!

Comment: @AnnaJeanine yeah that isn't going to work with a ManyToMany because it wouldn't know which RestaurantServing you are looking for. You can look at admin inlines for inspiration on how to handle this sort of editing.

Comment: Solved it by using `fields=['serving',]` !